# What kind of controls should I use in Windows Phone 7 to make a "star" control

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

I show some items from the database in the list and I want the user to be able to mark some of  them as favorites. The best way would be to show some star icon for user to click on which then would turn into slightly different star to indicate that the item is now favorite. What controls should I use for those stars? Could I bind them to some boolean property of the item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use vector graphics to achieve this without using png icons.

I created this style a while a go, basically it is for `CheckBox` but I think it also works for `ToggleButton` by simply changing the `TargetType` from `CheckBox` to `ToggleButton`.

By setting the `IsChecked` of either `CheckBox` or `ToggleButton` to `True`, the star will be filled with the accent color of the phone.

**The Style**

```
    <Style x:Key="StarCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2000000" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="check" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2000000" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Path x:Name="check" Stretch="Fill" Height="48" Width="48" UseLayoutRounding="False" Data="M16.000002,0 L19.77688,12.223213 L32,12.222913 L22.111122,19.776972 L25.888546,32 L16.000002,24.445454 L6.1114569,32 L9.8888807,19.776972 L8.574415E-09,12.222913 L12.223121,12.223213 z" Opacity="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Path x:Name="stroke" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="48" Width="48" UseLayoutRounding="False" Data="M16.000002,0 L19.77688,12.223213 L32,12.222913 L22.111122,19.776972 L25.888546,32 L16.000002,24.445454 L6.1114569,32 L9.8888807,19.776972 L8.574415E-09,12.222913 L12.223121,12.223213 z" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,0,8,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Apply the style**

```
    <CheckBox Content="unchecked state" Style="{StaticResource StarCheckBoxStyle}" />
    <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="checked state" Style="{StaticResource StarCheckBoxStyle}" />
```

**How they look**

[image]

Comment: Awesome! A note for newbies (like me): a good place to add styles is App.xaml - http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-Implicit-Styles

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [ToggleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to do this. Keep 2 star images in your project, one for clicked and the other for not clicked. You can use data binding along with the `IsChecked` property to switch between the 2 images.

XAML:

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsFavorited, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <ToggleButton.Content>
    <Image Source="{Binding FavoriteImage}" />
  </ToggleButton.Content>
</ToggleButton>
```

C#:

```
Image ClickedImage = new Image() {
  Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/clicked.png", UriKind.Relative));
};
Image NotClickedImage = new Image() {
  Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/not_clicked.png", UriKind.Relative));
};
bool _isFavorited = false;
Image _favoriteImage = NotClickedImage;

public bool IsFavorited
{
  get { return _isFavorited; }
  set
  {
    if( _isFavorited != value ) {
      _isFavorited = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged( "IsFavorite" );

      FavoriteImage = _isFavorited ? ClickedImage : NotClickedImage;
    }
  }
}

public Image FavoriteImage
{
  get { return _favoriteImage; }
  private set
  {
    if( _favoriteImage != value ) {
      _favoriteImage = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged( "FavoriteImage" );
    }
  }
}
```

The class containing the code behind needs to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) interface.

Comment: Can you show some xaml how to use binding to switch between images?

Comment: @JuozasKontvainis I've added to the answer, wrote all that from memory so there may be syntax errors. But it should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](http://www.technicalypto.com/2012/07/windows-phone-75-ratingreview-control.html) for a list of star controls available for the silverlight toolkit for the windows phone.